# Typeorm entity methods doesn't appears

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, backend, typeorm

I have configured the simple custom application with 'ts-node', and as an ORM I trying to configure (by instructions of docs) **typeorm**. so there happening a weird thing, the editor cannot see any method of the entity.

the actual error looks like this: Entity.findOne method doesn't exist in "typeof Entity".

in tsconfig.json **experimentalDecorators**, **emitDecoratorMetadata** are enabled

**reflect-metadata** module is imported in index.ts,

I hope someone can give me some good information thanks!

Here are some code snippets

**tsconfig.jsos**

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,                      
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

**database/index.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./entities";

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "sqlite",
  database: "./database.db",
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true,
  entities: [User],
  subscribers: [],
  migrations: [],
});

AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => {
    // here you can start to work with your database
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

**entities/user.ts**

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    telegram_id: string

    @Column()
    nickname: string

    @CreateDateColumn()
    public created_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    public updated_at: Date;
}

User.findOne //findOne doesn't exists [[PROBLEM AT THIS LINE]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the BaseEntity:

```
export class User extends BaseEntity {
```

(and add BaseEntity to your typeorm imports)